# Golang google cloud functions using go modules fail build when importing subdirectories

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a google cloud function using go modules and I am having problem with it picking up code in subdirectories when using go modules.

It appears that inside the gcloud functions deploy build it is duplicating the package name. So for instance locally (and what i expect is this import)

`import "github.com/lwaddicor/gofunctionmodules/demoa"`

however it will only work in the gcloud functions deploy if set to

`import "github.com/lwaddicor/gofunctionmodules/gofunctionmodules/demoa"`

If anyone has any ideas what is happening here it would be much appreciated. Thanks

## Structure

```
 demoa/demo.go
 func.go
 go.mod
```

#### go.mod

```
module github.com/lwaddicor/gofunctionmodules

go 1.13
```

#### func.go

```golang
package gofunctionmodules

import (
    "net/http"

    // This is what i would expect, and it builds locally but it wont deploy
    "github.com/lwaddicor/gofunctionmodules/demoa"
    // With this one it deploys but locally wont build
    //"github.com/lwaddicor/gofunctionmodules/gocloudfunctions/demoa"
)

// Demo demonstrates the issue with package management in cloud functions
func Demo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write(demo.Demo())
}
```

```golang
package demoa

// Demo returns a demo string
func Demo() []byte {
    return []byte("demo")
}
```

Then deploying a new cloud function using

```
gcloud functions deploy demofunction --entry-point Demo --project my-demo-project --runtime go113 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

```
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.                                                                                                                                                                                                       
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: {"error":{"errorType":2,"canonicalCode":2,"errorId":"32633c29","errorMessage":"
serverless_function_app imports
github.com/lwaddicor/gofunctionmodules/gofunctionmodules imports
github.com/lwaddicor/gofunctionmodules/gocloudfunctions/demo: git ls-remote -q origin in /layers/google.go.gomod/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/48848540be122d75f1d2e6549925c34394ce402803530dc7962ab1442de3b180: exit status 128:
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information."}}
```

Edit: removed the github link as it just downloaded the dependency from the public github repo. Changed demo package to demoa to prevent using cached github copy

Comment: How do you deploy on Cloud Function? What is the command used?

Comment: Hey, i've updated the question with the deployment command

Comment: The more I look at this the more it seems like an issue with the beta go 1.13 runtime, if i switch the deploy command and go mod file to 1.11 it deploys properly

Comment: You got a point. I would ask you to try in lower version. You can open a case to the support. Interesting issue!